# Cannot run elixir application from powershell

Tags: powershell, elixir

When I type `iex -S mix` in PowerShell I get this error:

```
Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'mix'.
At line:1 char:1
+ iex S mix
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

What is the correct way to write the '-S mix' after the 'iex' command to get the same effect typing it in cmd would do? This is an issue with me not understanding PowerShell syntax I believe.

Comment: Is `iex` something to do with elixir?

Comment: What exactly is `-s` supposed to be? `iex`, which is an alias for `Invoke-Expression`, does not have any parameters that are named or begin with `S`.

Comment: @PaulHicks yes iex stands for interactive elixir, i was trying to run it not Invoke-Expression

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that `iex` is an alias in Powershell, short for `Invoke-Expression`. If you're trying to run a command `iex.exe`, `iex.bat` or `iex.cmd`, you'll have to specify it in some unique way: an explicit (or full) path, or even just adding the application's extension may be enough. That way, Powershell won't try to run `Invoke-Expression`.

`Get-Command` can clear this sort of thing up for you:

```
PS C:\Dir> Get-Command iex

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Alias           iex -> Invoke-Expression 

PS C:\Dir> Get-Command cmd

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Application     cmd.exe
```

It doesn't seem to be possible to list both the command type and path at the same time: if you want to see which `iex` is which, you can use this form:

```
PS C:\Dir> Get-Command -All iex -Syntax
Invoke-Expression
C:\windows\iex.bat
```

You can find out more about how Powershell decides which command to run in Microsoft's [technet library](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848304.aspx).

Comment: Ah good call; I missed the final important inference that he was probably trying to call something else. I'd add that using `Get-Command iex` would show exactly what PowerShell was trying to run, and that would clear it up for him, and I'd include a link to [about_Command_Precedence](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848304.aspx).

Comment: Done as suggested.

Comment: Nicely done; perhaps also mention `-All` to show _all_ forms of a given command, in descending order of precedence. Quibble: You don't necessarily need a full _path_; in the case at hand, adding the _extension_  is sufficient; i.e, using the full _filename_: `iex.bat`.

Answer (score 16):

For anyone else who may see this question:

Short answer--to run iex from within Powershell type `iex.bat`. In this particular case `iex.bat -S mix`

Answer (score 4):

If you use Elixir across different platforms and don't need yet another source of inconsistency (such as needing to remember use `iex.bat` instead of `iex`) you can remove the `Invoke-Expression` alias like so:

```
Remove-Item alias:\iex -Force
```

Now you can `iex -S mix` or whatever to your heart's content. Just be aware that this can conflict with other scripts you might run which assume `iex` is aliasing `Invoke-Expression`. For example I've had problems with the Azure SDK when un-binding `iex`, but I don't do Elixir and Azure dev on the same machine any more and I haven't run into any other issues yet.

If you want to have this happen automatically, add it to your Powershell profile. Easiest way is running `notepad $PROFILE` from Powershell and then add `Remove-Item alias:\iex -Force` near the end of your profile script.